Ubuntu Server installation use LVM OS physical volume as a whole device
I'm trying to do a Ubuntu Server VM installation by using the OS physical volume as a whole device without any partitions, but I can't manage to complete the disk configuration.
Is it possible somehow to remove all partitions (boot, etc.) and use the OS physical volume as a whole device to make it more flexible and skip the need for fdisk for future resizes?

You'll need an EFI partition and a /boot partition independent of the LVM volumes.  /boot and EFI aren't suited to work with LVM volumes and things will not work if you try to exclude an EFI partition and a /boot partition.
